# android map not showing in signed app

Tags: android, sign

I have developed an app which uses google map. The problem is when I sign this app and then download it from some link say dropbox or any other, the map does not show up. I have created a new Google map key as well but not working at all. Any idea...???

Comment: Did you change the reference to the key in your xml ?

Comment: i have created a new google map key for market. but not working..

Comment: When you declare your map in an xml layout, you must specify the key, like that (have you done it ?) :     <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="Your Maps API Key"
    />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you signing the app and getting the Google API key with the same keystore. If it is, then you should use the keystore with which you have signed your app for marketing/publishing...

Answer (score 0):

You probably checked most of the things already (as I did).
My problem was solved when I created an Api Key (with debug key+project package name) in one google account to use during development time....
and I created another Signed Api Key (signed keystore+project package name) on another google account. 
Apparently you cannot have more than one API key for the same package name (even if the keystore is different!) on the same google account.

I ended up with a development time Api key on one google account and another Publishing Api key on another account. Yet, another chapter closed on the Google Maps Googlemares.